# Having trouble with monodevelop

Tags: c#, mono, httpwebrequest, monodevelop

I have just installed monodevelop from ubuntu software centre and created a solution. I am trying to do WebRequest.create(url). But it keeps throwing "The authentication or decryption has failed". What am I doing wrong? If I am not doing anything wrong what should I do to make the above work!

I have searched about this but I couldn't come  up with a solution that will fix my problem!

Here is what I do ...

```
public static string AccessURL(string url, string postcontent)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postcontent);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        return responseFromServer;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far, that demonstrates this problem, please?

Comment: Are you accessing a `https` site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error suggests that you are trying to access a SSL/TLS encrypted resource. Mono does not trust any these sites per default and is up to the developer to determine whether you want to access that resource or not. More about this in [mono's security FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Security).

So one way to do this is to implement a ServerCertificateValidationCallback in your class:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

public class MyAwesomeProgram
{
    public MyAwesomeProgram() 
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                ValidateServerCertficate;
    }

    private static bool ValidateServerCertficate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate,
        X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslpolicyerrors)
    {
        //This is where you should validate the remote certificate
        return true;
    }

    public void FetchAwesomeStuff (string url) 
    {
        var wr = WebRequest.Create (url);
        var stream = wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream ();
        Console.WriteLine (new StreamReader (stream).ReadToEnd ());
    }
}
```

There are more examples in the [mono documentation about using Certificate Policies and Trusting Roots](http://www.mono-project.com/UsingTrustedRootsRespectfully). **Notice** the sample above ignores the security and accepts all certificates, even those you might not trust. This is not recommended to use!

Comment: It says ServicePointManager is obsolete. Use ServerCertificateValidationCallback. If I use that It says that it does not exist in the current context!

Comment: Just updated my answer to use the ServerCertificateValidationCallback instead.

Comment: Thank you very much it is working fine for me now! Will this work for both http and https calls?

Comment: Yep, it should work with both. The ServerCertificateValidationCallback  will be called when needed.

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, at what point in your code example is FetchAwesomeStuff() called??

Comment: @PaulG it is not called. You simply call it when needed. Nowadays I would probably use HttpClient instead it is much more clean when using it async with .NET 4.5 async/await.